# Can object data be transfered or linked while maintaining the origin of the target object?

Tags: linked-data

I'm trying to copy or link object data from a source object to a target object but maintain the origin position of the target.  I can't figure it out...is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this with Python or just within Blender's UI?

Comment: @ Robert Gützkow Blender UI